# How to reload custom fields after validation failure in keycloak

Tags: keycloak

How to reload custom fields after validation failure in keycloak, other form attribute are reloading but custom attributes are not loading.

form attributes

```
value="${(register.formData.email!'')}"
```

custom attributes

```
id="user.attributes.phone"
```

Answer (score 1):

Try changing to:

```
value="${(register.formData['user.attributes.phone']!'')}"
```